# Is there a cordova plugin for capturing video

Tags: cordova, capture

Is there a cordova plugin where its possible to autostart a capture of video or audio or taking picture without user actively presses any button?

Or do I have to go native? Or build my own cordova plugin?

Comment: BipBip is 10 hours of googling enough?

Comment: BipBip - so what did you find about this when you googled?

Comment: Of course I know about that plugin. But. as you can see I ask if there is a plugin that "autostart a capture of video", "without user actively presses any button". Maybe you should read a question before you answer it?

Comment: have you found any plugin to autostart video recording in cordova?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this plugin first to see if it answer your needs

> **Backgroundvideo**
>
> A simple Cordova/Phonegap plugin to capture video and then display it onscreen via a transparent overlay without affecting
>   app functionality.

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/io.iclue.backgroundvideo
hope it helps, ;)